# Include external jars while exporting java project in eclipse

Tags: java, jar, external-dependencies

I have developed a program that includes external jars also. Now I need to convert this program to a runnable jar (It has main method) and place it another location.

But how to include the external dependencies along with this conversion . I dont want other to download the external jars again and again.

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project then go to `Export` -> `Java` -> `Runnable JAR File` and there select `Package Required libraries into generated JAR` radio box

Comment: Thanks. Thats works fine. Can anyone tel me, how can i commit external jars in SVN ?